# How to scroll UITableView to a certain position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to scroll my UITableView 2 cells down when clicking on a button. The total height for the shift downwards is 100px. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13):

Set the `contentOffset` property.

```
[aTableview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,100)];
```

Comment: Here in Swift 4: 
`self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20 ), animated: true)`

Answer (score 5):

If you know what cell you want to scroll to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

otherwise use the contentOffset property or scroll by pixels http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW26

Answer (score 4):

swift 3 version of the answer:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y :100), animated: false)
```